# Date format in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, nodes, datetime-format

I just want to help with the print date like below.

```
Thu Sep 06 2018 18:18:26 GMT+0530
```

I used

```
console.log(new Date())
```

but Output of that is

```
2018-09-06T12:48:25.776Z
```

So, I don't know how to convert it.

Comment: Checkout this other question and answer [How to format a date String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved.

```
new Date().toString();
```

This line will convert

```
"2019-02-24T20:11:15.213Z"  =>  "Mon Feb 25 2019 01:38:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

Thank you guys for spent the time on my question.

Answer (score 5):

I used dateformat (npm install --save dateformat):

```
const dateFormat = require('dateformat');
console.log(dateFormat(new Date(), "ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss UTC" ));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some third party module to do that, like [`moment`](https://momentjs.com) or [`date-fns`](https://date-fns.org). Or create the string manually.

For `moment`, see this: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

For `date-fns`, see this: https://date-fns.org/v1.28.0/docs/format

For constructing the format manually, take a look at various `Date` object methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Ya, I familiar with Moment, thanks for that. But here, I don't want to extra packages.
BTW, problem solved. Just add "new Date().toString()."
Thanks for your answare.

Comment: Then you will need to do the formatting yourself via `Date` object getters.